# Ionic with visual studio always give node.js not installed. Even when I am using Node.js (6.7.0). Which runs android from Node command prompt

Tags: android, node.js, windows, ionic2

Ionic with visual studio always give node.js not installed. Even when I am using Node.js (6.7.0). Which runs android from Node command prompt.

I want to add Windows platform to my ionic.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, when you add windows as a platform in your ionic project and then build it, it creates a visual studio project in the directory which you can easily open by just clicking on it. At what stage are you getting this error and what is the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: I have build Android app with ionic. Facing issue while importing same for windows phone.